# Display any given MySQL SELECT query as a HTML table using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Sample Query 1 -

```
SELECT ID,NAME FROM USERS
```

Sample Query 2 -

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID as ID, Customers.CustomerName as Name, Orders.OrderDate as Date
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers
ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;
```

How can I load title headings to an array in PHP?
I mean 
**ID,NAME** in *Query 1* and **ID,Name,Date** in *Query 2*

**This is what I'm trying to do :**

I'm creating a PHP function to make HTML table automatically from any given MySQL-Select query

This where I'm up to now

```
function createTable($query) {
    $sql_link = Connect_MySQLi_DB();// Database Connection
    $sql_link->set_charset("utf8");
    $result = $sql_link->query($query);
    $headings = array('ID','Name','Date');//I need this array to create automatically
    echo '<table>';
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($x = 0; $x <= (count($headings) - 1); $x++) {
        echo '<th>'.$headings[$x].'</th>';
    }
    echo '<tr>';
    while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        echo '<tr>';
        for ($x = 0; $x <= (count($headings) - 1); $x++) {
            echo '<td>' . $row->$headings[$x] . '</td>';
        }
        echo '<tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

So I need to create that **$heading** array automatically. 
If I can do that, this function can display any MySQL-Select query as a HTML table

Comment: Pass an array of keys to your function and loop to print the headings? Or you could loop through your query and use regex to extract the key for each item before an operator

Comment: Yes it is possible, but actually I'm letting users to run their own SQL queries, so it may not be the best solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this is how I made this function to work (Thanks Hynner for your excellent suggestion),

```
function createTable_from_sql_select_query($query) {
    $sql_link = Connect_MySQLi_DB();// Database connection
    $sql_link->set_charset("utf8");
    $result = $sql_link->query($query);

    // Adding Missing array_column Function for Old PHP Versions (<5.5)
    if (!function_exists('array_column')) {

        function array_column($array, $column) {
            $ret = array();
            foreach ($array as $row)
                $ret[] = $row[$column];
            return $ret;
        }

    }

    $headings = json_decode(json_encode($result->fetch_fields()), true);
    $headings = array_column($headings, 'name');

      $return = '<table>';
      $return .= '<thead><tr>';
      for ($x = 0; $x <= (count($headings) - 1); $x++) {
      $return .= '<th>' . ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', (strtolower($headings[$x])))) . '</th>';
      }
      $return .= '</tr></thead><tbody>';
      while ($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
      $return .= '<tr>';
      for ($x = 0; $x <= (count($headings) - 1); $x++) {
      $return .= '<td>' . $row->$headings[$x] . '</td>';
      }
      $return .= '</tr>';
      }
      $return .= '</tbody></table>';

      return $return;
}
```

Now anyone can convert any SQL select query to a HTML table.

Comment: This answer is outdated / not modern.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using mysqli then [fetch_fields](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php) seems to do the job.

EDIT:
Example:

```
$res = $db->query('SELECT A.id,A.a,A.id + B.id AS idd FROM A natural join B');
var_dump($res->fetch_fields());
```

Returns information about columns A.id, A.a and about the idd column (both tables have other columns). I omitted some fields from the output in order to make it shorter.

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#3 (13) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(2) "id"
    ["orgname"]=>
    string(2) "id"
    ["table"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["orgtable"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    // more fields here
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#4 (13) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["orgname"]=>
    string(1) "a"
    ["table"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["orgtable"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    // more fields here
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#5 (13) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "idd"
    ["orgname"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["table"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["orgtable"]=>
    string(0) ""
    // more fields here
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes it actually returns headings, but looks like it ignores AS statements in a SQL query!

Comment: According to the manual it does consider the alias. (Check out the difference between `name` and `orgname` under `Object properties` in the manual)

Comment: @cyberboy: I tried it and it returns alias in `name` field and original column name in `orgname` field.